# Maven deployment configuration is not valid to deploy Mule 4 application in Mule standalone

Tags: maven, mule, maven-3, mulesoft, mule4

I'm deploying Mule 4 application in Mule standalone server 4.2 to start mule runtime(mule.bat)and command (`mvn package deploy -DmuleDeploy`) from the project directory but I'm getting below mentioned error.
I have added my plugin from the pom.xml.

Where am I going wrong to deployment configure in pom.xml?

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Deployment configuration is not valid, : No deployment configuration was defined. Aborting. -> [Help 1]

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                 <developmentType>standalone</developmentType>  
                  <muleHome>E:\IDFC\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.2</muleHome>
                  <muleVersion>4.2.2</muleVersion>    
                  <target>E:\IDFC\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.2\apps</target>
                  <targetType>server</targetType>                                                          
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try a configuration like it is [documented](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/deploy-on-premises#mmp-deploy-standalone):

```
 <configuration>
    <standaloneDeployment>
      <muleHome>${mule.home.test}</muleHome>
      <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
    </standaloneDeployment>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: already tried that one. For that case getting error mule run time is not running : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Execution default-deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7:deploy failed: Mule Runtime is not running! Aborting. -> [Help 1]

Comment: And your mule server is running?

Comment: yes mule server is running. Is there anything i'm missing in pom.xml?

Comment: @Devendra Maybe. Try -X in your maven command for more informations

Comment: this is showing in -X
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are

Comment: Did you use `mvn -X package deploy -DmuleDeploy`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start Mule Runtime Standalone as a Windows service or Unix daemon. Do not to use /bin/mule command

It worked for me

See reference on how to start Mule Runtime as service or daemon:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).